# How to make a Timer continue counting down when not in the same tab?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, intervals, countdown

**TIMER INTERVAL PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to make a timer, but when I click off of the *Timer* tab the *Timer's* countdown stops **(interval stops?)**. I tried using some jquery for the **$(window).focus** to continue counting down. I was unable to figure that out...

```
var timerInterval;
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!timerInterval)
        timerInterval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    if (!timerInterval)
        timerInterval = setInterval(startTimer, 10);
});
```

Here is the code for my Timer: https://codepen.io/0cean-Man/pen/NWyRPRX

*DISCLAIMER: The Jquery is not working on codepen, I don't know how to make the js Jquery compadible on codepen.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make setInterval also work when a tab is inactive in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927284/how-can-i-make-setinterval-also-work-when-a-tab-is-inactive-in-chrome)

Comment: I looked at that but i don't really know exactly how to implement it into my own code...